# How to maintain one copy of things like JS files and views

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My ASP.Net Core MVC project consists of 3 website projects, plus associated unit test projects, all collected in a single solution. Each of the website projects relies on common stuff, such as JavaScript libraries (under wwwroot/js/...) and views (under views/...). Is there some feature that lets me package up these files (none of which, as far as I know, can live in a NetStandard library project) and "install" them in all of my website projects so I only need to maintain them in a single place?

A razor class library (RCL) almost does what I want to do, but I want to be able to reference my JavaScript library from views in all three website projects. I also want the bundler/minimizer to be able to find my common JavaScript and CSS files. As far as I can tell, RCL only allows the Razor Pages in the RCL to access the static content (things like my JavaScript and CSS files) in the RCL.

EDIT:

After more thought, I've come to the conclusion that what I'm asking for simply can't be done "out of the box". In order to work correctly, the debugger and the bundler/minimizer need to find js and css files in the project's directory tree. What I'm asking for is a way to have something like a "reference project" that contains these "shared" files. I'm thinking that it's time for the "science project" approach: I'll create a reference project that contains the shared files, and run some code (at build time? via MSBuild? via unit test code?) that updates the files in the project from the reference project if they don't match.

Comment: If it's common enough, a dedicated CDN might be appropriate depending on the use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, here's what I wound up doing:

In my 3 website projects, I have common files in several places:

- Views/Shared
- wwwroot/js/MyJsLibrary
- wwwroot/css/MyCssLibrary

I created a "reference" project that contains copies of the common files in these folders. Then I created a unit test that simply verifies that the files in the "reference" project exist and are identical to files in each of the 3 websites.

No automated magic to keep the folders in sync. If someone changes one of the common files then the unit tests will fail until someone copies the updated file to the website projects and to the "reference" project.